# Deserialisation Issue For Nullable Foreign key Field Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

While Deserialization of the nullable foreign key field. Getting the error :

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'foreign_field'

**This issue was not coming till Django-Rest-Framework Version:** 3.6.4

Found the cause of the issue(Removed **None check** and **ObjectDoesNotExist check** isn't handling None instance) : [Link](https://github.com/rpkilby/django-rest-framework/blob/3.6.4/rest_framework/fields.py#L96)

> Why this check is removed?

Is there any workaround that can handle the Nullable foreign key field?

**Tried Following things** :

- Tried setting the default value: Didn't Work
- Writing the Serializer Method isn't feasible(Lots of changes in existing Code).

Edit:

Model Structure:

```
class Demo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Demo1(models.Model):
   demo = models.ForeignKey(Demo, default=None, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Serializer :

```
 class Demo1(ModelSerializer):
     demo = CharField(source='demo.name')
     class Meta:
         model=models.Demo1
         fields = ('id', 'demo')
```

Comment: *"Tried setting the default value: Didn't Work"* Can you show that configuration?

Comment: We can't help with just general considerations. Please show your code.

Comment: @Linovia @ JPG Check it out sample model code

Comment: @JPG The main problem is that they have removed the None check and it doesn't come under ObjectDoesNotExist Exception on link : https://github.com/rpkilby/django-rest-framework/blob/3.8.0/rest_framework/fields.py#L101

Comment: Show an example which can be reproduce the error

Comment: There is an issue while you giving some default value to your foreignkey which cant be None in any case.

Comment: what does your serializer look like ? your view ?

Comment: @Linovia Added serializer

Comment: @MayankPratapSingh How this is possible. That field was already having None values. I didn't get your point, Can you please elaborate more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution :

```
class Demo1(ModelSerializer):
 demo = CharField(source='demo.name', allow_null=True)
 class Meta:
     model=models.Demo1
     fields = ('id', 'demo')
```

After putting **allow_null** in the serializer.it worked! but didn't understand, What is the point? if we have already put **null=True** in the model.